# Windows 2003 cluster not able to initiate

Tags: cluster, windows-server-2003

I am having trouble getting a service started in windows 2003.

This is the cluster log, not able to deduce what is wrong either.

Any help would be appreciated, tks.

As it is with any log, it is exceeding the limit of this textbox, so here is the pastebin link
http://pastebin.com/EUWeAEL0

Answer (score 0):

You receive error 5051. That means the cluster node is unreachable.
The cluster node name may have the same username in AD. If that is the case, just renaming the NODE cluster.
Check the network port were the node is connected. It may be a connectivity problem there. Also, make sure DHCP Client service is enabled and IP configurations are correct.
If nothing of the above works, goto (regedit) `HKLM\SYSTEM\CCS\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\` and remove the disabled components there.

Comment: The cluster node name may NOT ? have the same username in AD.  u mean?

Comment: The name of the cluster node must be different for any username present in AD.